# CSS3 bounce animation not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation

I've got a bounce-in animation set on a span element in my HTML. The animation is fired using a setTimeout JQuery function. Now, the animation works great in Chrome, however, it's not responding in Firefox. Here's the css:

```
.bounceIn {
  -webkit-animation: bounceIn .75s;
  animation: bounceIn .75s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
}

0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
}

20% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
}

40% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
}

60% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
}

80% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
}

100% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
}


@keyframes bounceIn {
0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% {
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
}

0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
}

20% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
}

40% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
}

60% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
}

80% {
-webkit-transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
}

100% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
}
}
```

Here is my JQuery

```
$('#score').hide();

setTimeout(showScore, 1500);

function showScore(){
$('#score').show(); 
}
```

The span has an id of "score" and the class is "bounceIn" - Any leads would be greatly welcomed! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this example!

I have tested in firefox v31.0.

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: I've updated the question with my JQuery - none of the examples work in FF, I have a feeling it's how I'm calling the animation vs. FF

Comment: UPDATE: I've narrowed it down to FF won't recognize the class on the span. ie. <span id="score" class="bounceIn">text</span>. If I place the animation elsewhere, it works. So it's not the animation, it's the span vs. class issue